# Multiple installs

Tags: install

Are multiple installs allowed. This is for a single project. I'm the President of the company and I need the install on my computer but I also need my web designer to have access. This is a single license for a single site. Is this ok?

Answer (score 2):

According to [ExpressionEngine Licence](https://expressionengine.com/license) it allows you to do copies for 2 purposes:

1. Making Copies

> You may make copies of the Software for back-up purposes, provided
> that you reproduce the Software in its original form and with all
> proprietary notices on the back-up copy.

2. ExpressionEngine Installations:

> An ExpressionEngine license purchase allows a single “live”
> installation in a production environment and ancillary “development
> use only” installations as needed to support the live installation
> (such as development and a staging servers).

That means you can create a single licence copy for your developer and designer to make development and/or edits on your site. so they can make changes, approved by person and then make same changes on LIVE without breaking live site.

I hope this can help.